# Visa free travel to Philippines on Japan Visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visa-free-entry, philippines

I am an Indian citizen and have a valid Japan Visa which has allowed me to travel visa free to Philippines once.
Now I want to travel again to Philippines and my Japan visa is still valid.

- I am not sure if I can just go ahead and book my travel or should
  confirm with Philippines consulate if I can use same visa to travel
  multiple times.
- This time my purpose of travel is to just to meet few friends , does this qualify as tourism? Website mentions visa free travel is for tourism  https://newdelhipe.dfa.gov.ph/index.php/2014-04-14-03-10-05/78-consular-services/108-visa-application-requirements

Last time I tried to apply for Philippines visa but they didn't accept my application as I had Japan visa. So I am a bit confused if I should apply or try for visa free travel.

Any guidance here will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Indian citizens who has visa to  Australia, Canada, **Japan**, Singapore, United Kingdom, United States or a Schengen Area state does not require visa to philipines for 14 days. There is no problem using the same visa twice.

Yes. Meeting friends counts as tourism.

I have traveled to Manila using Singapore visa. Border agent just looked at my visa card and gave it back. Didn't note anything.

*Note: Reasonable limits apply. If you are trying to live for a long time there, or just leaving and entering for another 14 days will attract attention and will cause problems for you.*